# php5 copy sub-strings from string separated by space?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.6

I am using php5 and have a script which will return IP addresses of the client.
Executing script using shell_exec() function. Now the output is like this: *192.168.10.40 192.168.10.41 *. 
Now I need to store this in an array. I used preg_match() but it is not working.

Here is the code using preg_match() :

```
$test = shell_exec("/www/dhcp.sh");
$pattern='/([^ ]*) /';
preg_match($pattern, $test, $new);
```

preg_match() is returning 0;

Here is the one I used explode() :

```
$test = shell_exec("/www/dhcp.sh");
var_dump( explode(' ', $test ) );
```

I also used explode but I am getting the result as: 
*array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "192.168.10.40 192.168.10.41 " }*
Can anyone tell me how can I split the string into an array?

Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: You should show the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode to split your string:

```
explode(' ', '192.168.10.40 192.168.10.41'));
```

which gives you

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "192.168.10.40"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "192.168.10.41"
}
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

Comment: The IP address will be changing and the script may return nothing if the devices are not connected.

Comment: then you have to verify that the string return by your script is not empty before exploding the string

Comment: Yes the script is not returning empty. But I have to pass the output of shell_script() to explode function. Can I pass as an argument?

Comment: What is the exact output of your script then ? What kind of argument you want to pass ?

Comment: The output of the script will be like this: **192.168.10.40 192.168.10.41**

Comment: Then the explode is the right thing to do : explode(' ', '192.168.10.40 192.168.10.41'));